# Add sessions to Grub

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu, session

I have Xubuntu installed on an old P3 computer.  I also installed packages for lubuntu and Kubuntu.  Grub has changed since I played wit it last so many years ago and I want to add the other sessions to Grub's choices.  I could just make lots of HD partitions and install all separately but too much of a waste.  Also, many years ago there was a startup utility that would allow you to change Grub and do lots of other start up type of things in a nice GUI.  I would then go back and look at what it did and experiment with the new commands I learned.  Anything like that now?  Oh, the version I have is the latest LTS, 12.04
Oh, and UbuntuForums has been down for quite a while now.  Anyone have any new info?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify how many ubuntu installations do you got? Or did you install many desktops into one ubuntu installation?

Answer (score 1):

Grub bootloader recognizes only partitions and installed operating systems in them, not sessions. You installed two more sessions to your current partition so no other separate partitions was added.

You can choose what session you want to load from the login screen, not grub.